# IntelliJ breakpoint in scala foreach not working

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, foreach, breakpoints

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 16.1.2 and Scala 12. When setting breakpoints in foreach loops, they don't get hit.

Breakpoints above the foreach work and get the tick in the breakpoint (valid breakpoint) but the ones in the foreach don't get the tick and the program doesn't break there either.

I tried invalidating the IntelliJ Cash, restarting my PC and IntelliJ, rebuilding maven - nothing worked.

This are the VM parameters I'm using, but I've also tried it without any, which didn't help:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-XX:StartFlightRecording=filename=recording.jfr
-server
-Xms1G
-Xmx4G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
```

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
class RunTestCasesAction extends AbstractAction {

  def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) = {
      val parent = methodToGetParentComponent() //breakpoint works
      getFileName(parent).foreach { testFileName => 
        val dialog = new SomeDialog() // breakpoint doesn't work    
      }
  }

  private def getFileName(parent: Component): Option[String] = {
    val baseDir = getExportDir
    val fc = new JFileChooser(baseDir)
    val rc = fc.showDialog(null, "Select test file")

    if (rc == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) Some(fc.getSelectedFile.toString) else None
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are not performing `foreach` on empty collection?

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried a simple app with for loop in the main method with Scala 2.12.1 and it worked.

Comment: by "setting them in foreach loops", do you mean inside the `for { a<-b }` part, or in the `yield {...}` part?

Comment: @Rumid yes, the code is executed but i cannot break

Comment: @JustinKaeser i perform a foreach on aOption[String] like this

`val foo:Option[String] = Some("bar")`
`foo.foreach { s => ... }`

Comment: @simon, could you put an exact example of your code, and where did you put a breakpoint? It matters. Look on this example: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206640735-How-to-use-Breakpoint-Condition-

Comment: You can expand your code block within `foreach` and make there breakpoints.

Comment: @Rumid i hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is creating new objects and assigning them inside a `foreach` loop.
This has no effect on other part on the projects.

Compiler optimizes your code and this way this code block is never executed. This `val dialog = new SomeDialog()` are created inside `foreach` and this objects are immediatelly destroyed, cause their scope is only inside `foreach` loop, so there is no point of doing it so.

If you want to go inside the loop, put there something what matters, what will be reusable. Eg. you can collect this objects.
Make sure compiler will not optimize your code this way.

Probably you could try to use some compiler optimizations flags, but I am not sure about that.

Here are informations on [how debuggers work](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1).